# if first name not exists in database it should print smessage but it is going else condition and inserting

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `AddStudent`(in Firstname varchar(50)
,in Lastname varchar(50)
,in email varchar(50)
,out smessage varchar(500) )
BEGIN

SELECT first_name FROM web_student_tracker.student where first_name in (Firstname);

if Firstname=NULL then set smessage="Name not exsists";

else 

insert into student(first_name, last_name, email) values(Firstname,Lastname,email);


END IF;
```

END

Comment: Try *is null* instead of *=null*

Comment: Thank you it's working

Comment: I have added at as an answer. Feel free to accept it

Answer (score 0):

It must be *is null* not *= null*.

```
if Firstname is NULL then set smessage="Name not exsists";
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if firstname exists, you need to copy the rsult to a variable that you check

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `AddStudent`(in Firstname varchar(50)
,in Lastname varchar(50)
,in email varchar(50)
,out smessage varchar(500) )
BEGIN

SELECT first_name INTO @firstname FROM web_student_tracker.student where first_name in (Firstname);

if @firstname IS NULL then 
    set smessage="Name not exsists";
else 
    insert into student(first_name, last_name, email) values(Firstname,Lastname,email);
END IF;

END
```